# Xamarin Android Firebase user: how to get created date

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, firebase-authentication

I'm using the Nuget package Xamarin.Firebase.Auth in my Xamarin Android project, and I would like to know how to find a signed in user's created date. In Java, the Firebase user has a `Metadata` property that contains the UTC creation date, but in this Nuget package, I can't find an equivalent property.

Is there a way to obtain this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FirebaseUser's Metadata was added in the version `11.6.0` `com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0` on November 6, 2017.

The currently published `Xamarin.Firebase.Auth` is "out of date" and is using the   version `11.4.2` from October 3, 2017 (about 6 public releases behind the Google official releases).

FYI: The current Firebase-Auth is at version **`16.0.2`** and was released June 14, 2018.

Personally, I typically build the Firebase binding (and most of the Google services) from source due to the lag in releases from Microsoft/Xamarin.

#### `com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0`

> SDK Version 11.6.0 - November 6, 2017
>
> Added user metadata to FirebaseUser to help determine if the user is new.